# how to send array of objects using NSNotification -> userInfo in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsnotificationcenter, userinfo

`userInfo` only sends data of type `anyObject` , so I need to cast my array of Meals 
to `anyObject` without crashing and then recasting it to `[Meal]`, unfortunately it crashes here ...

```
var anyOrder =  NSMutableArray()
    for meal in ordered { // ordered is array of meals [Meal] ...
        anyOrder.addObject(meal as! AnyObject) //crashes here 
    }
```

I want to be able to cast it or find any other way to send it using `userInfo` in `NSNotification`, thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need to case Meal to AnyObject ? Can't you just send that meal array without that case ?

Comment: Is Meal a struct by any chance?

Comment: userInfo only takes AnyObject variables

Comment: NSMutableArrays can only hold objects. A struct is not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to know the type of Meal.

If Meal inherit AnyObject, you can cast that easily.

```
class Meal: AnyObject {
    // something
}

var ordered = [Meal(), Meal()]

var anyOrder =  NSMutableArray()
for meal in ordered {
    anyOrder.addObject(meal as AnyObject)
}
```

If not so, whether or not Meal can cast AnyObject depends on inheritors.
Considering from crash, you failed to cast it. So the runtime error happen.